# How To Use Netlify Split Testing Based on a Condition?

Tags: netlify, hugo, ab-testing

**newbie here**

I want to try the Netlify split testing feature which basically split the traffic randomly on multiple GitHub branches (but keeps the same URL).

But what I need to do is instead of splitting the traffic randomly on different versions, I want to split the traffic based on conditions, especially by using the document.referrer request.

For example, a user from Facebook will see the site from branch A, and others will see branch B.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Netlify has built-in referrer targeting options built into their split testing product. At least, not according to their [docs](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/split-testing/). Tools like Google Optimize and Optimizely provide options to split test against the HTTP Referer header, which is the URL of the site the user was on before they hit your page.

Netlify does, however, mention the following on the above page:

> We set a cookie called nf_ab to ensure that the same visitor always gets the same branch. By default, the value of the cookie is a random number between zero and one and is configured out of the box to ensure that your site visitors have a consistent experience. If you'd like your visitors to manually opt in to a split test, you can also use client-side JavaScript to manually set the value of the nf_ab cookie to a branch name, which Netlify's CDN will read and serve accordingly.

So I believe your only option would be to write custom client-side JS that checks the [HTTP Referer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) value and sets the value of the `nf_ab` cookie used by Netlify to the branch you want that user to be served a version of your site from.